# Single source shortest path in JGraphT for unweighted graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, shortest-path, jgrapht

[JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/) has many implementations for shortest paths (Dijkstra, Belman Ford and more)

I need a single source shortest path for an unweighted graph.

**Here are my questions (specific to JGraphT):**

1. First, I assume that using Dijkstra for unweighted graphs is wasteful (uses a priority queue which has slower queue deque than a regular queue that BFS uses, and since on unweighted graph all weights are 1, this is not really adding any value). Is my assumption correct?
2. Assuming the answer to 1 is "yes", then I assume I'll use `BreadthFirstIterator` other than rolling my own, (unit tested, and as simple BFS is, I'm sure I'll have some corner case bug, even Java's binary search had an integer overflow thank's to a bug that Josh Bloch himself introduced and it wasn't solved until 2006!). But the question is, there is still a (very small) step to take from a raw BFS to actually getting the single source shortest paths, should I write my own `UnweightedSingleSourceShortestPaths` class? or is there one hidden in JGraphT core library that I can just plug into?

Comment: In case of unweighted graph,  all edges have the same weight, so the priority queue won't be relevant, Dijkstra in that case will be simple BFS on the graph.

Comment: Yes, but if Dijkstra uses a heap priority queue, queue and dequeue are O(LogN) no? So if I do a Dijgstra for an unweighted graph vs do a BFS do the same graph, won't the BFS be faster? (although they both will give me the same results...)

Answer (score 0):

Since I think I found the answer to the 2nd question, I think it also answers the 1st question (if JgraphT's Dijkstra was the most efficient for the simple case of all weights = 1, then why would CDK create their own?)

Here is the answer to #2 - yes, there is an open source (LGPL) solution: https://github.com/cdk/cdk/blob/master/legacy/src/main/java/org/openscience/cdk/graph/BFSShortestPath.java